# Simple 2 Players Tic Tac Toe Python

Tags: python

I am setting up a 2-player tic tac toe game (it's a homework). But I don't understand what mistakes I make.

```
def start_move(board, letter, move):
    board[move] = letter


def next_player(board, player_1_letter):
    #determine 2 players' letter position
    if player_1_letter == "X":
        player_2_letter = "O"
    else:
        player_2_letter = "X"

def if_board_full(board):
    #if the board is full, back to "True"
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if free_space(board, i):
            return False
    return True

print("Welcome to tic tac toe !!!")

while True:
    #renew the board
    the_board = [" "] * 10
    player_1_letter, player_2_letter = input_letter()
    turn = first_turn()
    print(turn + " will go first.")
    gamestarts = True

    while gamestarts:
        if turn == "Player who choose O.":
            gameboard(the_board)
            move = firstplayermove(the_board)
            start_move(the_board, player_1_letter, move)

            if winner(the_board, player_1_letter):
                gameboard(the_board)
                print("Congratulationsss!!!!" + player_1_letter + " has won!")
                gamestarts = False
            else:
                if free_space(the_board):
                    gameboard(the_board)
                    print("Tie!")
                    break
                else:
                    turn = "Player who choose X"

        else:
            #player 2's turn
            move = next_player(the_board, player_2_letter)
            start_move(the_board, player_2_letter, move)

            if winner(the_board, player_2_letter):
                    gameboard(the_board)
                    print("Player 2 has won!!! Congratulations!")
                    gamestarts = False
            else:
                if free_space(the_board):
                    gameboard(the_board)
                    print("Tie!!!")
                    break

                else:
                    turn = "Player who choose O"

    if not play_again():
        break
```

I expect the game (code) is ok (for me)... but it keep saying.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\projectdemo.py", line 122, in 
>       start_move(the_board, player_2_letter, move)   File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Python\projectdemo.py", line 51, in start_move
>       board[move] = letter TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 50 you set `move = next_player(the_board, player_2_letter)`. The function `next_player()` doesn't return any value, so `move` doesn't get a value.

Change `next_player()` to this:

```
def next_player(board, player_1_letter):
    #determine 2 players' letter position
    if player_1_letter == "X":
        player_2_letter = "O"
    else:
        player_2_letter = "X"
    return player_2_letter
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `move` as anything in `board[move]`. It doesn't know what to do with it.